# Get image URL from avatar

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get an image url from the following page:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/428510f3-ce59-4c97-9981-75fdc3291d97

Image source is base64 string (bytes of images)

Is it possible to get it from code like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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" alt="">
```

I have found usercard.js file that has following line of code:

> ...img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${AvatarData}"...

but I cannot find where AvatarData is retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no URL.  That base64 data is the actual contents of the image file.

Comment: Yes but that content is retrieved from some file (url), right? It must be some js function that get content from some url (based on user id I suppose).